# ¿como puedo hacer para saber si hay algo introducido en una caja de texto con tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

quiero saber si hay algo introducido en una caja de texto para poder crear un if a partir de ello.

```
def funcIngualConv():

    resultFinalConv = conversorTexto1.get()
    resultado1Conv = float(resultFinalConv)*1000
    resultadoConv1 = Label(ventana, text = str(resultado1Conv), bg = "pink", font = "Calibre 10")
    resultadoConv1.grid(row = 14, column = 0, padx = 25, pady = 5)
```

aquí iría un if si es que hay algo en la caja de texto

```
    resultFinalConv2 = conversorTexto2.get()
    resultado2Conv = float(resultFinalConv2)*100    
    resultadoConv2 = Label(ventana, text = str(resultado2Conv), bg = "pink", font = "Calibre 10")
    resultadoConv2.grid(row = 14, column = 1, padx = 25, pady = 5)
```

Comment: Si deseas comprobar si la entrada no está vacía o si no sólo contiene espacios: `if not conversorTexto2.get().split():`

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te encuentres muy bien. Esto lo puedes solucionar con el método `get()`, te recomiendo [leer los métodos](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_entry.htm) de las **entry** (entradas de texto) de tkinter.

Te dejo un ejemplo claro de como lo hice, debe de haber alguna acción que solicite el `get()`, como un botón en este caso, y puedes hacer una condición comparando un `String` vacio.

```
import tkinter as tk

def comparar():
    if entrada.get() != "":
        print(" ¡Hay algo en la entrada! ")

master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, text="Entrada").grid(row=0)
entrada = tk.Entry(master)
entrada.grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Button(master, text='Accion', command=comparar).grid(row=3,
                                                        column=1,
                                                        sticky=tk.W,
                                                        pady=4)

tk.mainloop()
```

En este caso, pregunto si hay algo diferente de un `String` vació. Si hay algo, imprime " ¡Hay algo en la entrada! "